# How to separate a Django app in order to make part of its GitHub repo private

Tags: python, django, git, github

I have hired a contractor to do some web development work on my app and would like to only give them access to certain parts of my GitHub repo (I would like to keep the Python utility files private). The stack is Python/Django/GitHub/Heroku. Based on other Stack Overflow posts, it sounds like the solution is to create two GitHub repositories, one public and one private, and manage both with Git.

The problem is that if I move the Python utility files to another repo outside of my Django root project, then I'm not sure how to import those files into my Django project.

I went down the route of moving the Python files to an external location and then trying to import them via `sys.path.append('/mypath')` in the Django settings file and alternately tried packaging my python files into a separate module and then installing it via pip but have run into issues with both of these methods.

Is there a suggested approach for how to best separate these two parts of the code base, such that the Django project is able to import the Python files?

Answer (score 0):

**Do not push secret files to the repository** as `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`. Keep them private. You should specify them in Heroku config as [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application).

So if you once pushed the secrets to the repository I hardly suggest you to create a new one without it (because of commit history). Then you have to import environment variables in the `settings.py` file like.

```
os.environ['SECRET_VARIABLE_NAME']
```

Thats it. I guss that you do not mean `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` but keys from aws or from credentials to production database. But even `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` should be kept safely and not be pushed to the repo. It's better practise to send the key other way to the developer instead of pushing it to the repository.

### Do not ever push your secret keys to the repository!

more sources:

[Handling Sensitive Keys | Ultimate Django](https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/handling-sensitive-keys/)